# Is it possible to find what apps friends are using?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-canvas

I know a friend's app can publish to my newsfeed, but is there any way to query a user for the apps they have "installed" (either canvas or connect).

I'm not sure if this is possible using the facebook UI, nevemind the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like it. You can query to see if your friends have installed *your* app at `/me/friends?fields=installed` when you are authenticated as your app.

Comment: When I browse apps in the App Center, there is a category for "Friends' Apps", and it tells me which of my friends are using each of the apps in the list. I guess facebook keeps this data for itself?

Comment: There is a lot of data Facebook keeps for itself.

Comment: Any idea if an app can automatically hide itself from being shown in the "Friends' Apps" category?

Comment: A user can control the visibility of each app they use. See Settings->Privacy Options->Apps